# Sums of Powers as Sums of Stirling Numbers and Falling Factorials

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I am able to prove the following identity:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n k^p = \sum_{j = 0}^p {p \brace j} \frac{(n+1)^\underline{j+1}}{j+1},$$
where $p$ and $n$ are non-negative integers, ${p \brace j} = S(p, j)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind, and $x^\underline{m} = x(x-1)\cdots (x - m + 1)$ is the falling factorial function.

My question: Is this identity commonly known in combinatorics?

Comment: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/2/Boyadzhiev-2013.pdf ... page 265 or 14?

Comment: That is a slightly different identity (note that the bounds of summation on the RHS are different in the two identities).

Comment: I cannot find the formula on the wiki pages for both Stirling numbers of the second kind & Faulhaber's Formula, It is definitely remark worthy.

Comment: It turns out what you found actually IS the correct identity, with a typo in the bounds of the RHS summation!

Answer (score 5):

That's simply a consequence of the Hockey stick identity for the binomial
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {k^{\,p} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,p} {\left\{ \matrix{
  p \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}k^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,p} {j!\left\{ \matrix{
  p \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {{{k^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } } \over {j!}}} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,p} {j!\left\{ \matrix{
  p \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,p} {j!\left\{ \matrix{
  p \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}\left( \matrix{
  n + 1 \hfill \cr 
  j + 1 \hfill \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,p} {j!\left\{ \matrix{
  p \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,j + 1\,} } } \over {\left( {j + 1} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,p} {\left\{ \matrix{
  p \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,j + 1\,} } } \over {j + 1}}}  \cr} 
$$

The *"Summa Potestatum"* ($\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {k^{\,p} }$)
has been the subject of many works, by various great Mathematicians over the centuries, in modern times 
starting with [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).
So there is a vast literature, resulting in many different formulations, some of which are
$$
\eqalign{
  & S_m (n) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {k^{\,m} } \quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integer }m,n} \right. =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left\langle \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\rangle \left( \matrix{
  n + j \cr 
  m + 1 \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\;j!\;\left\{ \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  j + 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {m + 1}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  m + 1 \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\;B(j)\;n^{\,m + 1 - j} }  \cr} 
$$
where the angle brackets denotes the Eulerian Numbers 1st kind, the curly brackets the Stirling Numbers 2nd kind, and $B(j)$ the Bernouilli Numbers.

Thus in some of the papers on the subject you can find the relation with the Stirling Numbers,
for instance in the renowned "Concrete Mathematics", pag. 289.

Comment: Nice proof! Do you know if this identity shows up in any interesting work?

Comment: are you interested in this identity in itself or on the sum of $k^p$?

Comment: I'm interested in this identity in itself.

Comment: @RobertAdkins: added some reference, for you to start and dig inside.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a reference off the top of my head, but this is a straightforward application of the [calculus of finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Calculus_of_finite_differences) and I expect it's well known in some form or another. Here's one way to structure the proof.

The key player is the **forward difference operator**, which takes as input a sequence $a_n$ and returns as output the sequence

$$(\Delta a)_n = a_{n+1} - a_n.$$

> **Claim 1:** $\displaystyle \Delta {n \choose k} = {n \choose k-1}$ (a restatement of [Pascal's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)).

The sequences $n \mapsto {n \choose k}$ have the following remarkable property: every sequence can be written *uniquely* as an infinite sum

$$a_n = \sum_{k \ge 0} c_k {n \choose k}$$

and we can determine the coefficients $c_k$ as follows: taking forward differences $i$ times gives

$$(\Delta^i a)_n = \sum_{k \ge i} c_k {n \choose k-i}$$

and substituting $n = 0$ gives

$$(\Delta^k a)_0 = c_k.$$

(This should remind you a lot of computing coefficients of a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) by differentiating.) Hence:

> **Claim 2:** If $a_n$ is any sequence, then
>
> $$a_n = \sum_{k \ge 0} (\Delta^k a)_0 {n \choose k}.$$

(Various alternate proofs of this result are possible. I think there are two ways to do this using generating functions, and you can also do it by writing $\Delta$ in terms of the **shift operator** $(Sa)_n = a_{n+1}$.)

Note that this sum terminates if and only if $a_n$ is a polynomial in $n$.

Now, instead of computing the "finite derivative" $\Delta$ of a sequence, we want to compute the "finite integral," namely

$$(\Sigma a)_n = a_0 + a_1 + \dots + a_n.$$

The two are related by the "fundamental theorem of finite calculus," which is just the observation that $(\Delta \Sigma a)_n = a_{n+1}$. This leads to:

> **Claim 3:** $\displaystyle \Sigma {n \choose k} = {n+1 \choose k+1}$ (a restatement of the [hockey stick identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity#Hockey-Stick_Identity)).

This lets us compute the "finite integral" of any sequence given the sequence of all of its finite differences: writing

$$a_n = \sum_{k \ge 0} (\Delta^k a)_0 {n \choose k}$$

and applying $\Sigma$ to both sides gives

$$(\Sigma a)_n = \sum_{k \ge 0} (\Delta^k a)_0 {n+1 \choose k+1}.$$

(This should remind you of integrating a Taylor series term by term.)

It remains to compute the finite differences $(\Delta^k a)_0$ in the particular case that $a_n = n^p$. At this point it will be convenient to introduce the shift operator $S$ mentioned above so we can write $\Delta = S - I$, giving

$$\Delta^k = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} {k \choose i} S^i$$

which leads to

$$(\Delta^k a)_0 = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} {k \choose i} a_i.$$

Substituting $a_n = n^p$ gives one of the well-known formulas for [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), up to a factorial factor.

This entire argument can be recast in terms of generating functions as well.

Comment: Great proof! My proof also uses finite calculus, though a slightly different approach where we use the fact that $\Delta(x^{\underline{m}}) = m x^{\underline{m-1}}$.