# An explicit version of Faulhaber formula

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

In this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula we have the original formula due to Faulhaber which used to calculate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^p$ for any fixed couple $(n,p)$ but using Bernoulli numbers. 
here i need to prove this explicit version of the formula :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^p=\sum_{j=0}^p\frac{n^{\underline{j+1}}}{(j+1)!}\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^{j-k}\binom{j}{k}k^p\biggr)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in having a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549753/sums-of-powers-as-sums-of-stirling-numbers-and-falling-factorials). Here 
$\left\{\matrix{
 p\cr j}
  \right\}$ denotes the Stirling numbers of 
second kind (with parameters $p,j$).